# Science fiction novel where the scientists discover a cosmic square wave signal

Tags: story-identification, novel

Here's what I remember for sure:

- A group of scientists discovered some cosmic phenomenon signal, that after some more research was described as a square wave.
- When the cosmic wave was positive, good things happened.
  When the cosmic wave was negative, bad things happened.
  I think it was equated to the universe's 'luck signal'.
- At some point in the book (or books) they travel to a different world, where some other entities tried to control this wave, to make it positive most of the time,  but it backfired somehow.
- I've read it about 15 years ago I think, so it's not anything new.
- It might be a book series rather than a single book.

Things I'm unsure of:

There's a scene where they encounter robotic sentries, and those sentries kill anything taller than like, 3ft,  because their creators are around 3ft tall.
1 of the humans encountered a sentry, but he was crouching down at the time (to poop? idk) so the sentry didn't register his height correctly and spared him.

Comment: Sounds like something Sheckley might write